# How to generate HTML test report for python script

Tags: html, python-3.x, reporting, appium

I am working in python + Appium to automate an Android App. I have created 7 scripts and imported all the scripts in a single script named `Main_module_testing.py.`

Now I want to generate an `HTML Report` for my test. In which it automatically creates Pass/Fail result. I have tried `HTMLTestRunner.py`, but its throwing so many error related to IOString, Unicode, decode etc.

Can anyone please tell how to fix it or generate an automatic HTML test report?

Comment: have you tried http://automationtestingutilities.blogspot.com.es/p/reporting.html ?

Comment: I think this is for Selenium + Java. But i want only in Python +Selenium. I don't think it will be helpful for me.
Please suggest something else.

Comment: what are the errors you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Python selenium test with HTMLTestRunner to generate report in html follow below link:

[HTMLTestRunner](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html)

[Click Here](http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2014/09/road-to-generate-html-report-for-python.html)

Let me know if you see any issue.

Comment: I am facing following issue:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\HTMLTestRunner.py", line 94, in <module>
    import StringIO
ImportError: No module named 'StringIO'

Comment: Are you following same as mentioned in example, Also first run example mention in HtmlTestRunner package

Comment: About which example in HTMLTestRunner package u r talking?

Comment: i have followed the same setps as mentioned in the thread which u mentioned. But still its showing me an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python_Workspace\My_Automation
\test_HTMLTestRunner.py", line 3, in <module>
    import StringIO
ImportError: No module named 'StringIO'
Please help me to fix this.

Comment: As i have search and found that in Python 3.x, 'StringIO' changed to 'from io import StringIO'. After doing this its not showing me an error which i mentioned earlier.
But after fixing this issue now its showing me another error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_HTMLTestRunner.py", line 114, in test_main
    unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(My_Main_module),
  File "C:\Python34\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 74, in loadTestsFromTestCase
    if issubclass(testCaseClass, suite.TestSuite):
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class